# Reorder dynamic text field ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic text field which allows user to add/remove the field. Once the selected field is removed, the text field `ID` will be automatically reorder. So far this is what I have done but sometimes it will remove two row together and occurs duplicate text field ID.

```
 function hapus(i) {
     var $el = $("#field" + i);
     $el.nextAll('.fieldwrapper').each(function (idx, el) {
         $(el).find('[id]').addBack().attr('id', function () {
             return this.id.replace(/\d+$/, idx + i)
         }).filter('input[type="button"][onclick]').attr('onclick', 'hapus(' + (i + idx) + ')')
     })
     $el.remove();
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("body").on("click", "#addField", function () {

         var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
         var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"field" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldwrapper\"/>");
         var hidden = $("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hiddenField_" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname\"/>");
         var fpartNo = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"partNumber_" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname\"/>");
         var fDescription = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"description_" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname\" readonly />");
         var fPrice = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"price_" + intId + "\" readonly class=\"fieldname\" style=\"width:80px\"/>");

         // remove textboxes and dropdown boxes
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"hapus("+intId+");\" />");
         removeButton.click(function () {
             $(this).parent().remove();
         });
         fieldWrapper.append(hidden);
         fieldWrapper.append(fpartNo);
         fieldWrapper.append(fDescription);
         fieldWrapper.append(fPrice);
         fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
         $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
         });
     });
```

Demo here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/8/)

Comment: _sometimes it will remove two row together and occurs duplicate text field ID_.. On what scenarios?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try on jsfiddle. You just keep on adding and removing the field and the problem will occur. It works fine when it is hard code for example `hapus(2)`. This will remove 2nd row of the table and it works fine.

Comment: You can use jQuery chaining to simply the append's to fieldWrapper.  `code`fieldWrapper.append(hidden).append(fpartNo).append(fDescription).append(fPrice).append(removeButton);`code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var count = 1;

 function hapus(i) {
     var $el = $("#field" + i);
     $el.nextAll('.fieldwrapper').each(function (idx, el) {
         $(el).find('[id]').addBack().attr('id', function () {
             return this.id.replace(/\d+$/, idx + i)
         }).find('input[type="button"][onclick]').attr('onclick', 'hapus(' + (i + idx) + ')')
     })
     $el.remove();
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("body").on("click", "#addField", function () {

         var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
         var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"field" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldwrapper\"/>");
         var hidden = $("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hiddenField_" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname\"/>");
         var fpartNo = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"partNumber_" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname\"/>");
         var fDescription = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"description_" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname\" readonly />");
         var fPrice = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"price_" + intId + "\" readonly class=\"fieldname\" style=\"width:80px\"/>");

         // remove textboxes and dropdown boxes
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"hapus("+intId+");\" />");
         //removeButton.click(function () {
             //$(this).parent().remove();
         //});
         fieldWrapper.append(hidden);
         fieldWrapper.append(fpartNo);
         fieldWrapper.append(fDescription);
         fieldWrapper.append(fPrice);
         fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
         $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);

         });
     });
```

I made two tiny changes. First, replacing the `filter` to `find` in hapus() function. Second, remove `removeButton.Click`, it caused your removing problem.
Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/16/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p8hu7qnh/15/)**

Well, the `.filter` wasn't the one you are supposed to use in this scenario. It should have been `.find` instead inside the `function hapus`. `.filter` wasn't changing the target inside its `onclick` and it kept as it is, thus causing removal of its next `element` too on its `click`.

```
$el.nextAll('.fieldwrapper').each(function (idx, el) {
         $(el).find('[id]').addBack().attr('id', function () {
             return this.id.replace(/\d+$/, idx + i)
         }).find('input[type="button"][onclick]').attr('onclick', 'hapus(' + (i + idx) + ')')
})
```

Comment: Thanks guru. Henry made two tiny changes and it worked perfect.

Comment: @Ethen Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)